# Where to look up the date format specifiers used in cocoa / cocoa touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

For example: `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];`

I guess there's a list somewhere that shows all those date format specifiers, but can't find any. The NSDateFormatter docs seem to not mention these.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It uses [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Also note: NSDateFormatter changes *a lot* with iOS 4, so make sure you read the documentation carefully.

Comment: And that link can be found in the date formatting docs; specifically, [the Date Formatters chapter of the Data Formatting Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW5). (At the top of that page, it says “This article describes how you use date formatters using Mac OS X v10.4 and later and iPhone OS.”) That document is, in turn, linked to from the NSDateFormatter class reference.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: The upcoming NSDateFormatter reference documentation will also include a direct link to the standard as well.

Comment: For iOS 7 and above please refer to this version of the documentation: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns