# dateFromString producing NIL value - solution

Tags: ios, datetime, null

Why is this producing a NIL value ?

```
NSString *danceDateValue = self.yourvariable.text;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString: danceDateValue];
NSLog(@"date input value: %@", danceDateValue);
NSLog(@"date input value: %@", date);
```

Comment: Wrong format... dupe hundreds of times.

Comment: check This post

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076370/where-to-look-up-the-date-format-specifiers-used-in-cocoa-cocoa-touch][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076370/where-to-look-up-the-date-format-specifiers-used-in-cocoa-cocoa-touch

Comment: What answer do you expect if you don't even show your input string?

Comment: @MartinR I expect it to return a date value in Month/Day/Year format.  And the input string is 11/11/13...

Comment: @Toploulou that link shows a 3 yr old post where the end link 404s.  However I've skimmed the documentation on NSDateFormatter...

Comment: Your date format string needs to match the format of you input string. MM-dd-yy does not match 11/11/13....

Comment: Ahhh well *THAT* explains it.  Problem solved!!  Thanks @rdelmar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is that the format of the input has to match the format string!

In this case -> [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"]; its format of MM-dd-yy must match the input string which was 11/11/13, unfortunately they didn't match, however, once I reset the following line to what it should be, all was well...

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

Thanks to @rdelmar for the solution!